# React Lifecycle Video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was creating this React component and I was astonished by the fact that when I clicked on the video I got `false` on console immediatelly after the video started. I was expecting that it would print `true` when the video started, and `false` when it finished. I think I'm confusing the lifecycle of this particular component, and I would be really grateful if someone could clarify this to me.

```js
const Video = ({src, type, index, isAutoPlay}) => {
  
  const [play, setPlay] = useState(isAutoPlay)

  const playRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (play && playRef.current) {
      playRef.current.play();
    }
    return () => setPlay(false)
  }, [play]);
  return (
    <>
      <video 
       className="slide" 
       ref={playRef} 
       onClick={() => {
                setPlay(true); 
                console.log(play);}}>
        <source src={src} type={type} key={index}/>
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: State changes are asynchronous. You can't `console.log` them on the next line. Print the state in the main body of the function, that will show current value

Comment: I put it there now, and I get a true output, and after that two false outputs. Shouldn't I get only one false output? UseEffect wasn't supposed to be activated only when I changed play value?